# react native push notification snooze

Tags: android, react-native, android-push-notification

I'm using https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification for local push notifications.
It also includes an options to have some buttons on the notification("actions"), which I can press on.

However, when I'm getting a notification, in order to have a response to that button(noti. action), the app should open(the only way I could work it around) and only then I can run my logic according to the action.

Because I have some troubles using react-native-push-notification for this(It simply doesn't work), I would like to implement this by my self.

This is the process I wish to have:

1. Push notification is showing up
2. The user clicks on snooze button(same like an alarm)
3. The application is still at *background*
4. The notification will be pushed again after some time.

What is the proper way to do such a thing?
It seems that I have to run a background task which is fired when the user presses the snooze button.
How can I use [HeadlessJS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android) for this? It is very to easy to implement the snoozing logic with JavaScript, the problem is to fire it.